# a finitely generated module of constant finite rank which is not free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $M$ be a **finitely generated** module over a commutative ring $A$.

If there exists a natural number $n$ such that for any prime ideal $P$ of $A$, $M_P$
is a free $A_P$-module of rank $n$, then $M$ is said to be of **constant finite rank**.

I have known every finitely generated projective module of constant finite rank over a **semilocal** ring is free.

I want to know whether there exists a finitely generated module of constant finite rank which is not free or not.

**If $M$ can be generated by $n$ elements $x_1,\cdots,x_n\in M,$ and $\dim_{A_P}(M_P)=n$
for any prime ideal $P$, we cannot find such examples.** One way goes
as follows: Consider the following map
$$\phi\colon A^n\rightarrow M,\ e_i\mapsto x_i,$$
where $e_i$ is the standard basis of $A^n.$ By localization, $\phi$ is an isomorphism. When $A$ is a **seimilocal** ring, we can prove $M$ can be generated by $n$ elements.

Comment: Why not take a projective module which is not free?

Comment: @Mohan cannot gurantee a projective module has constant finite rank

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is an integral domain , any finitely generated projective $A$-module $M$ has constant rank, equal to $\dim_{Frac(A)}(M\otimes_A Frac(A)),$ since for any prime ideal $P$, we have a canonical injection $A_P\to Frac(A)$.

Hence any example of a non free finitely generated projective module over an integral domain will do.

For $A$, you can take for instance a non principal Dedekind domain and for $P$ a non principal ideal of $A$.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thanks.